# Subversion repository ACL management with Redmine

Tags: automation, svn, acl, redmine

is there some way to repository acl management from Redmine? For instance, if I want to create a branch and assign ACLs to that branch, can this be done using redmine without having to manually fiddle with the configuration files?

Comment: Interesting. Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into the same problem and so far I've found [only this feature request](http://www.redmine.org/issues/2647) that might help you. At the moment I think I'll rather limit the user's repository access in redmine, and only limited account will be able to access it.